# How do I create a custom layout module in LyX for a special itemized list?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

How do I create a custom layout module in LyX for a special itemized list?

```
    \newenvironment{goalbox}[1][\unskip]
            {\begin{goalboxT}[#1]\begin{eBox}\ \begin{enumerate}}                
    {\end{enumerate}\end{eBox}\end{goalboxT}}

    \begin{goalbox}[Overview over my goals]
    \item Get things done...
    \item Get more things done...
    \item Get even more things done...
    \end{goalbox}
```

I would like to create a Lyx environment which allows me to

1. Enter the optional argument (Overview over my goals)
2. Use enumerate style

Ideally, I would like to have a different background color.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you give more details or example, and an example code you've tried?

Comment: I would be simply happy if anyone could point me to an example?

Comment: Iwill be hard if you don post any  precise specifications. Ypu can take a look at what can be done with the `enumitem` package.

Comment: Ok, I will add an example to make it fully clear...

Comment: I moved from Lyx to true latex editors, among other reasons, because I was to lazy to read the chapter 5 of  "Customizing LyX: Features for the Advanced User" (menu Help > Customization) but presumably should contain what you need, at least to show here your wrong try (that someone could fix more easily that starting from scratch).

Comment: @Fran: I have been digging through enumitem but even the code that I can find in LyX itself does not provide what I need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is the best answer to my own question that I could come up with:

```
Format 66

Input stdlyxlist.inc

Style Goals
  Category            "Personal Add-Ons"
  LatexName     "goalbox"
  LatexType           Environment

  Margin        First_Dynamic
  Align             Left

  LabelType     Static
  LabelString   "Goals of current chapter:"

  EndLabelType  Static
  EndLabelString      "End Goals"

  Font
    Color           blue
  EndFont
  LabelFont
    Color       blue
    Series      bold
  EndFont

  KeepEmpty 1
  Argument 1
    LabelString     "Chapter Goal"
    MenuString  "Overarching goal"
    Tooltip     "Specify the big picture goal"
    Mandatory   0
    Decoration  conglomerate
    AutoInsert  1
  EndArgument

  AutoNests
       Itemize, Enumerate, Description     
  EndAutoNests

  Preamble
       \newenvironment{goalbox}[1][\unskip]
            {\begin{goalboxT}[#1]\begin{eBox}\ \begin{enumerate}}                
            {\end{enumerate}\end{eBox}\end{goalboxT}}
  EndPreamble

  BottomSep        1
End
```

I hope it helps someone else as well.